# Use HTML inside a Rails translation file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, localization, translation

I have some translations in my Rails application (config/locale/[en|de].yml) and I use it in my views with `<%=t "teasers.welcome" %>`. Example:

```
teasers:
    welcome: "<strong>Welcome</strong> to the Website ..."
```

In Rails 2.3.8 this works just fine, with Rails 3, the HTML is escaped and translated to `&lt;`... How can I prevent this form this translation and use HTML in my translation files like in Rails 2.3.8?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I suppose it's because doing

```
<%= t("blah") %>
```

in rails 2.x, now is the equivalent of doing

```
<%=h t("blah") %>
```

when you're using rails 3.

From the [release note](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html)s:

> Switch to on-by-default XSS escaping
>   for rails.

To fix this, and once again from the release notes:

> You no longer need to call h(string)
>   to escape HTML output, it is on by
>   default in all view templates. If you
>   want the unescaped string, call
>   raw(string).

So just replace

```
<%= t("blah") %>
```

by

```
<%= raw t("blah") %>
```

Comment: The convention way is to use keys ending with `_html`.

Comment: Do be careful if you add dynamic data to the translations like using `<%= raw t "welcome", name:user.name %>`. If the user sets the `name` value to some javascript, you're having a XSS attack.

Answer (score 115):

Other than using `raw`, there's an other undocumented (but official) way to do so.
All keys ending with `_html` are automatically rendered unescaped.

Rename the key from

```
teasers:
    welcome: "<strong>Welcome</strong> to the Website ..."
```

to

```
teasers:
    welcome_html: "<strong>Welcome</strong> to the Website ..."
```

Comment: Actually it is documented, is here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-safe-html-translations

Comment: Doesn't work for attribute error messages